# How can open new tkinter window by threading?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want open a splash window using threading and show loading files page. 
I write a simple code to open a new window and close after 1 second:

```
import Tkinter as  tk
from threading import Thread as thread
import time

class T():  
    def det(self):
        self.x = tk.Tk()
        self.x.mainloop()
    def det2(self):
        self.x.destroy()

k = T()
ts = thread(target=k.det, args=())
ts.start()
time.sleep(1)
k.det2()
```

when try to run, all steps is ok but this code never finished! in `self.x.destroy()` it hanged. Why this happed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many searchs, I found this solution. Tk instance should not be created in the thread (`mainloop` sholud be outside of thread), but it can close in thread:

```
import Tkinter as  tk
from threading import Thread as thread
import time

class T():
    def det2(self,x):
        time.sleep(2)
        x.destroy()

x = tk.Tk()
ts = thread(target=T().det2, args=(x,))
ts.daemon = True
ts.start()
x.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

for something as simple as this you don't actually need threading, just use the `after` function:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.after(1000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want open `root` for _special_ time not for _constant_ time. This method close windows after `1000` millisecond while I am not sure how many time should be opened.

Comment: then i don't understand what you are asking for, this code sample would do what you asked for. can you explain how it falls short of your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Use `__init__` to create `self.x` outside `det`:

```
import Tkinter as  tk
from threading import Thread as thread
import time

class T():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tk.Tk()  
    def det(self):
        self.x.mainloop()
    def det2(self):
        self.x.destroy()

k = T()
ts = thread(target=k.det, args=())
ts.start()
time.sleep(1)
k.det2()
```

Comment: This code have this exception: `RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment`. While it finished normally, tk window dot not appear.